# Return 403 statuscode from Azure Function with queue output

Tags: azure-functions

I have the following function which adds an item to a queue. Is there anyway of returning other status codes then 500 and 200? I have a case where I check if the caller has access to the endpoint & want to return a 403 if they don't.

```cs
[FunctionName("AddToQueue")]
[return: Queue("queue")]
public async Task<PushRequestMessage> AddToQueue(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "")] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    if (!_accessRights.HasInternalAccess(req))
    {
        // return 403
    }

    return new Message()
    {
        Title = "Hello"  
    };
}
```

Comment: You need to change the return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw an `HttpResponseException` like this:

```cs
[FunctionName("AddToQueue")]
[return: Queue("queue")]
public async Task<PushRequestMessage> AddToQueue(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "")] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    if (!_accessRights.HasInternalAccess(req))
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }

    return new Message()
    {
        Title = "Hello"  
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can return an `HttpResponseMessage` like this:

```cs
[FunctionName("AddToQueue")]
[return: Queue("queue")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AddToQueue(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "")] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    if (!_accessRights.HasInternalAccess(req))
    {
        //return 403
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }

    return new Message()
    {
        Title = "Hello"  
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would ever work. HttpResponseMessage is very different from my own "Message" class. "Message" could be any POCO, and I don't see how I can return that through a HttpResponseMessage.